# Objective C rateview not show half image

Tags: objective-c, rate

I am using rateview like this page:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/1768/uiview-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-make-a-custom-uiview-in-ios-5-a-5-star-rating-view

It runs normally, but I cannot see half image show, like 1.5- 1.5-3.5..

Can someone help me know why? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem, just add some code in handlingTouchFunction

```
- (void)handleTouchAtLocation:(CGPoint)touchLocation {
if (!self.editable) return;

double newRating = 0;
for(int i = self.imageViews.count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    UIImageView *imageView = [self.imageViews objectAtIndex:i];
    if (touchLocation.x > (imageView.frame.origin.x)) {
        if(touchLocation.x <= (imageView.frame.origin.x + imageView.frame.size.width / 2))
            newRating = i + 0.5;
        else
            newRating = i + 1;
        break;
    }
}

self.rating = newRating;
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Use [FloatRatingView](https://github.com/glenyi/FloatRatingView) for Whole, half or floating point ratings control.

[image]

Comment: thanks you, but i want to fix the code in my web link and make it work with half star without use new lib.

Comment: I saw the note in my link page: " Note this doesn’t support “half-star” ratings but could easily be modified to do so."     I think it can be modified to make half star work